# Neural network linearity and non linearity

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, statistics, data-science-model

Is it right on my part to call:

- A neural network with only input and output layer (sigmoid) as linear (since it is a logistic regression)
- A neural network with more than one hidden layer non-linear (since weights interact with outputs from hidden layer and there is no way to write output as `op = w2x1+w2x2+b` like in linear regression)?

Please don't mark this as duplicate as none of the questions actually answer the question asked here. Thank you.

Comment: What if you have linear activation functions in the hidden layer? // What if you do a standard MLP but no activation function in the output node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are mostly correct. A feedforward neural network with a single layer and a sigmoid activation is a logistic regression which belongs to GLM type of models. Your second statement is unclear (weights interact with outputs) so I will try to break this down below:

Non-linear transformations (e.g. polynomial regression, logistic unit etc.) is often misread for non-linearity in model parameters (non-linear models).

As an example let's look at a feedforward neural network architecture. For $f(x)$ activation function and $w,b$ weights and biases, the output of a neuron from the first layer of a feed forward network would look like:

$$a_{11}=f(w_{11}x_1 + w_{12}x_2 + .. +b_1)$$

whereas the output of a neuron from the second layer neural of that neural network would look like:

$a_{21}=f(w_{21}a_{11}+ w_{22}a_{22} + .. + b_2)$, and given $a_1$ above $ \Rightarrow a_2=f(w_2w_1x+w_2b1+b2)$

$$a_{21}=w_{21}w_{11}x_1 + w_{21}w_{12}x_2+ .. + b_2$$

The multiplication between parameters (here $w_1w_2$) is what makes a model non-linear. In order to acquire that you need:

- Either multiple layers *OR*
- A non-linearity from the activation function e.g. if $f(x)=x^2$ even the output from the first layer of the neural network would be $a_{11}=w_{11}^2x^2 + b_2^2+w_{11}b_1x$ that qualifies as parameter multiplication in the $w_{11}^2$ factor and a non-linear model of a non-linear relationship with additive errors.

Hope it helps.

Sauces:

- https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2019/04/27/the-difference-between-linearly-separable-data-and-a-linear-classifier-in-machine-learning/
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/344658/110383
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71444/110383

Comment: "Single-layer" is confusing. Do you mean a network with one hidden layer or zero? // Even a network with no hidden layers does not have to be a logistic regression. It could be a linear model or any other kind of generalized linear model (or perhaps even a weirder activation function than GLMs use as link functions).

Comment: Single layer neural network, single layer perceptron are widely used in the literature afaik, e.g.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network#Single-layer_perceptron. On your second point you are right, a sigmoid activation needs to be in place so that it is a logistic regression - i have amended this mistake now.